# Let $\epsilon>0$. Find a polynomial $P$ such that $\lVert P-f\rVert<\epsilon$, $P(0)=f(0)$, and $P'(0)=0$, where $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on $[0,1]$, and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Find a polynomial $P$ on $[0,1]$ such that $P(0)=f(0)$, $P'(0)=0$, and
> $$\lvert P(x)-f(x)\rvert<\epsilon$$
> for all $x\in[0,1]$.

My attempt:
By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, there exists a sequence $\{P_n\}$ of polynomials on $[0,1]$ which converges uniformly to $f$. Since
$$\left|\left(P_n(x)-P_n(0)+f(0)\right)-\left(P_m(x)-P_m(0)+f(0)\right)\right|\leq\left|P_n(x)-P_m(x)\right|+\left|P_n(0)-P_m(0)\right|\text{,}$$
$P^*_n(x)\rightarrow f$ uniformly and $P^*_n(0)=f(0)$ for each $n$, where $P^*_n(x)=P_n(x)-P_n(0)+f(0)$.

How to choose a polynomial whose derivative at $0$ is $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $P(x)$ polynomial with $P(0) = f(0)$, and
$|f(\sqrt{x}) - P(x)|< \epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Then $|f(x) - P(x^2)|< \epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.